# bootcamp with windows 7 64bit?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, 64-bit

I have the new (2011) 27" iMac and need to run visual studio and some other .NET software development related software. What version of Windows 7 (home premium OEM - because it is the cheapest?) should I buy? 64bit or 32bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use more than 4gb of memory go for 64bit. If you don't care 32bit will run as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4410
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461